# How to set Multicolumn width (longtable latex) on Rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, kable, kableextra, gtsummary

I am having some issues with a table built on Rmarkdown to PDF output.

I am using gtsummary to summarise stratified data, then using to_kable_extra in order for export to PDF.

My code looks like this

````
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes

date: "2022-08-17"

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(gtsummary)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

```


```{r}
data <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3), Age = c(20,20,25),Area = letters[1:3])

    data %>%select(-id) %>%tbl_strata(strata = Area, .tbl_fun = ~.x %>% tbl_summary(missing = 'no'))%>%
  as_kable_extra(
    booktabs = TRUE,
    longtable = TRUE,
    linesep = ""
  ) %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(
    position = "left",
    latex_options = c("striped", "repeat_header"),
    stripe_color = "gray!15"
  )%>% column_spec(column = 1:4, width = '4cm')
```
````

The problem comes on the Latex output, with "column_spec" on R i can set latex columns width without issue.

However the multicolumns created for the stratified data I can not from R set their width, and that is my question. How can I achieve this without having to edit the .tex file by myself everytime I want to get this report done.

This is a piece of the Latex file, instead of what is actually happening : `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{a}}`; I need it to be `\multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}}{\textbf{a}}`

```latex
\begin{longtable}[l]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}> 
{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4cm}> 
{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4cm}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{a}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{b}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{c}} \\
```

Another possible solution for me would be to turn this multicolumns information to a regular row record susceptible to general column width.

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but you shouldn't want `\multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}}{\textbf{a}}`. Instead it should be `\textbf{a}` as the column is already `p{4cm}`.

Comment: The column width p{4cm} does not affect the multicolumn width at least for me. Resulting a column with 4cm width but the label on the multicolumn does not get affected by it (4cm) returning too wide table.

Comment: The point is that there shouldn't be a multicolumn

Comment: Those are created by the gtsummary tbl_strata function to stratify the data.

Comment: I gathered that, but instead of asking how to change their width, it might be better to ask how to remove them completely.

Comment: That would work great too or instead of removing them turning them to a regular record susceptible to general column width